# Json-server can not be installed, any other suggestion?

Tags: json, linux

I'm trying to develop a front-end application and going to use JSON. This is my first time doing this so I tried to install 'json-server' to get a restful API so I can get the file with XMLHttpRequest, but when I try to install json-server with npm like this, sudo npm install -g json-server, is just say "/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory".

Anyone know how to fix it or any other Rest API you can recommend? I have looked at github's api, but I can not for the life of me understand how it works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: More a Linux question then javascript or json. You may consider changing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory".

Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (or fix your PATH if you have it installed already).

Comment: That did the trick! Never connected the dots that node meant node.js. Ty!